# NoPlayerException runtime error with jmf app

Tags: java, swing, awt, jmf

hello im trying to create a simple video player with jmf. i think my code its ok but when i execute it i get a NoPlayerException. Here is the code of the player:

```
package reproductor;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author pollyox16
 */
public class repropanel extends JPanel{

    public repropanel(URL url){

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true);

    try{
    createRealizedPlayer().


    Component video= reproductor.getVisualComponent();
    Component controles=reproductor.getControlPanelComponent();


    if(video!=null){

    add(video,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    if (controles!=null){add(controles,BorderLayout.SOUTH);}

     reproductor.start();//con esto arrancamos el reproductor.
    } //end try


    catch(NoPlayerException e3){
    System.out.println("player not created");

    }
    catch (CannotRealizeException e){
    System.out.println("player not realized");

    }

     catch (IOException e2){
    System.out.println("io exception catch");

    }


    }




}
```

here is the code of the main application it only creates a JFileChooser and add the url to the player: here is the code of the main application:

```
package reproductor;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 *
 * @author pollyox16
 */
public class Reproductor{


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        JFileChooser selectarchivo= new JFileChooser();
        int resultado= selectarchivo.showOpenDialog(null);



        if(resultado== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){


        URL miurl=null;
        try{



        miurl=selectarchivo.getSelectedFile().toURI().toURL();

        }//FINAL TRY

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error en el main");       
        }


        if(miurl!=null){
        JFrame ventana= new JFrame("pollyox16");
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setSize(300,300);
        repropanel mireproductor= new repropanel(miurl);
        ventana.add(mireproductor);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: here is the exception stacktrace:

```
javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :file:/C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample%20Videos/Wildlife.wmv
    at javax.media.Manager.createPlayerForContent(Manager.java:1412)
    at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:417)
    at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:332)
    at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:527)
    at reproductor.repropanel.<init>(repropanel.java:34)
    at reproductor.Reproductor.main(Reproductor.java:52)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace when you get an exception

Comment: i just added the e3.stackTrace(). thank you please help me spot the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for: 
    file:/C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample%20Videos/Wildlife.wmv
```

WMV is ***not*** listed anywhere in the [JMF 2.1.1 - Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html).  A 'quick and dirty' test for any media is to load it into the JMF default player.  If that player won't load it, neither will any other JMF based app.

I have a page that offers some [JMF compatible media](http://pscode.org/media/#video) that you might choose to test your app. with.

---

JMF is very old, and has little support for newer formats.  If you can convert the video to a format JMF can read, it is fine at playing it, but it is not suited to being a generic 'media player' at this point in time.

Comment: thank you I was just using it for learning purposes. +1 :). also what api would you recommend to play media that is not that old. thank you.

Comment: I hear Java FX is good for media.  For 3rd party APIs see Xuggle or Jffmpeg.